# Convert text in PowerPoint 2011 to MP3 audio?

Tags: microsoft-office, conversion, text-to-speech

I know it's technically impossible to convert PowerPoint to MP3s.  What I really want is to have a speech synthesizer create an MP3 file with at least the key points from each PowerPoint slide.

Example:  Let's say I have the following PowerPoint presentation:

> **Uses for Microsoft Office**
>   Why spend that money on this software?
>
> Uses for Word
>
> - Word Processor
> - Nice templates
>
> *some image here*
>   image caption here

What the synthesizer would do is record a simulation of someone saying "Uses for Microsoft Office. Why spend that money on this software? Uses for Word: word processor, nice templates."

This would be more so that I can listen to a professor's lecture slides while doing something else (such as exercising).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe thi would be some help. I am not aware of any tool that would do exactly as you want. But there are tools that will convert plain text to voice, and save them as .mp3 files 
such as :

- [Listen](http://ctrlq.org/listen/)
- [Yakomite](https://www.yakitome.com/tts/text_to_speech/Welcome-to-YAKiToMe?b=None)
- [Vozme](http://vozme.com/index.php?lang=en)

And you can export text from ppt so you dont have to copy paste it from every page.
[Thre are some examples](http://pptgarden.blogspot.com/2011/12/3-methods-to-convert-powerpoint-to-word.html) of how it can be done, but i think maybe there are better ways.